# Cannot access $rootScope property from controller?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-rootscope

In angular's run block i am setting one property on $rootScope however when controller executes that property doesn't exists on $rootScope.

When application starts, in debugger i see "adal:loginSuccess" handler gets executed and $rootScope.isAdmin do get sets to "true", however when controller start executing the $rootScope.isAdmin doesnt exists on $rootScope. Why?
Below is my code

**app.js**

```
    var main = angular.module('mymodule', [
        'ngAnimate','ngRoute','Mycontrollers','AdalAngular'...

    ]);

    main.config(['$httpProvider','adalAuthenticationServiceProvider', function ($httpProvider,adalProvider) {  
        adalProvider.init(
            {
                // config Azure Client ID Here
            },
            $httpProvider
            );

    }]);

    main.run(["$rootScope", "$state", "API", "usSpinnerService",
        function ($rootScope, $state, API, usSpinnerService,) {      

             $rootScope.$on("adal:loginSuccess", function () { 
                       $rootScope.isAdmin = user.isAdmin;
             });

        }]);
```

**Controller.js**

```
angular.module('Mycontrollers', [])
    .controller('HeaderCtrl', ['$rootScope','$scope',   'adalAuthenticationService', function ($rootScope, $scope, adalAuthenticationService) {

    //$rootScope.isAdmin is set in angular's run block above
    //however $rootScope.isAdmin does not exists here, WHY????? 

    }])
```

Comment: the "adal:loginSuccess" event handler probably runs after the controller

Comment: how do i ensure adal:logingSuccess occurs first before controller start executing?

Comment: If you want to prevent a controller from loading until something else loads you can you a router `resolve` https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/provider/$routeProvider

Comment: we are using $stateProvider. Also can you please provider How we do that?

Comment: ui-router has the same feature https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki#resolve

Answer (score 0):

Because you have `var main = angular.module('mymodule', [...])`, so your app is named 'mymodule'; however, for your controllers you have `angular.module('Mycontrollers', [])`.  What you've done is instantiate a new instance of Angular.  Angular will only bootstrap the first instance of instantiation, so would need to use `angular.bootstrap`, but I'm guessing that's not actually what you want.  Instead, replace `angular.module('Mycontrollers', [])` with `angular.module('mymodule').controller(...)`.  Notice the lack of brackets.  Now you're using the module you already instantiated.

Comment: no thats not correct,  see my updated code. 'MyController' module is actually included in main..i didnt put whole code block..

Comment: That's not a module.  That's a dependency.  You can't give a controller to a dependency.  Also, my point about instantiating Angular again is still an issue.  Since it's being instantiated, it will not share the same $rootScope as the initial instantiated Angular app of 'mymodule.'

Comment: @ChrisStanley you can create multiple modules in Angular and they will all share the same `$rootScope`: https://plnkr.co/edit/jSYYfUpuQuAzQ5s2pbLn?p=preview

Comment: That's true.  I'll edit that out of my comment.  Don't know why I was thinking that.  Nevermind... I can't edit my comment for some reason - just this one.